# How can I add custom sidebar to my theme?

Tags: sidebar

How can I make my own custom sidebar for my blog when my theme does not provide an option to add a custom sidebar?

Comment: You need to change the theme code to have that widget area.

Comment: how can i do that? without knowing php ?

Comment: Well you need to know php to do that else find out a plugin which does that or find out someone who can do this for you.

Comment: is there somewhere this kind of plugin?

Comment: If your theme doesn't support sidebars you'll either need to find a new theme or contact a developer. What you're asking is to change the entire layout of your sites blog section to support something it doesn't support. This falls out of scope for a single question as being too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the widget area in your themes functions.php file. Your code should look something like this.

```
//register the widget area
function your_function_name() {
     register_sidebar(array(
         'name' => esc_html__('Sidebar', 'your_theme_name'),
         'id' => 'sidebar-1',
         'description' => esc_html__('Add widgets here.', 'your_theme_name'),
         'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
         'after_widget' => '</section>',
         'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
         'after_title' => '</h2>',
     )); } 

add_action('widgets_init', 'your_function_name'); //This hooks into WordPress wigets_init function.
```

You can learn more about widgetizing themes [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes). Another great place to learn and understand hooks, actions and filters is this [site](http://docs.presscustomizr.com/article/26-wordpress-actions-filters-and-hooks-a-guide-for-non-developers), it really helped me out. I hope this all helps. =)

Answer (score 0):

You should also create a sidebar.php template in your theme, embed the first code shared by @user53340 the add `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` anywhere you want the sidebar to show, you should also float the css class you used to wrap it to left or right just as you like.